# User-Defined Table Type - Dynamic SQL Function Call - Not switching databases (thows error)

Tags: function, t-sql, sql-server-2014, user-defined, variable-types

I need a SQL guru, this is driving me crazy... 
I'm getting an error when executing dynamic SQL with a user-defined Table Type:

Error:  Operand type clash: VariableTableType is incompatible with VariableTableType

Problem:  It doesn’t seem to really declare the VariableTableType in the [Database1] database even though the Use [Database1] is right above it.
The XT function has to run in the [Database1] database for it to work.

If I run the exec with the dbname, it works- ex: exec database1.dbo.sp_executesql @cmdTest – but I have many client databases that have the same database structure (different data) where I have to pass in the client database name so I can’t hardcode it that way.
If I make @dbname=’MainDatabase’ it will run – just doesn’t run against the right database.

[MainDatabase]
Contains main stored proc that has the dynamic SQL:
@dbname=’Database1’

```
      DECLARE @cmdTEST NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'USE '+@dbname +'
      DECLARE @t as dbo.VariableTableType
      INSERT @t
      SELECT VariableName,[Value],InstanceID FROM #tVarTble
      SELECT dbo.XT(''Test string'',7153,45,@t)RtnValue
      '
      exec sp_executesql @cmdTEST
```

Also tried passing in the VariableTableType and put the declaration outside of the dynamic sql.
--exec sp_executesql @cmdTEST,N'@t VariableTableType READONLY',t=@t

[Database1] (this function also exists in the [MainDatabase]

```
      ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[XT] 
      (
        @text nvarchar(max),
        @instanceID INT,
        @storeID INT,
        @vt dbo.VariableTableType READONLY
      )
      RETURNS nvarchar(max)
      AS BEGIN
      … code here
       RETURN @return
      END
```

VariableTableType exists in the [MainDatabase] and [Database1]

```
      CREATE TYPE [dbo].[VariableTableType] AS TABLE(
        [VariableName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
        [Value] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
        [InstanceID] [INT] NULL
      )
```

Comment: Its actually 2014.  When I tried the 3 names it worked with the exec database1.dbo.sp_executesql ... but I have to pass in the database name and can't just hardcode it.

Comment: You should be able to concat the DB name to use it in your dynamic SQL in the three-part form.

Comment: I can't use it on the VariableValueTable user-defined table type because it won't allow you to.  I have it dynamically putting Use [Database1] but the VariableValueTable acts like it doesn't see it.  Hence the error.

Comment: If I change the Select dbo.XT( function to just be SELECT * from @t - it works.  So it is something to do with the function call.  I tried it with database1.dbo.XT( and it doesn't work.

Comment: And it works if I just run it on Database1 (without dynamic SQL)

Comment: I have upvoted. Maybe somebody else can help.